# Understanding/Getting symbol type?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

```
public void SomeMethod(string sampleString) 
{   var helloworld = sampleString; }
```

Is it possible to determine if a particular symbol is a local variable, class field or method's parameter? e.g. if I call a FindSymbolAtPosition on the sampleString, will i be able to tell that the sampleString symbol is a method's parameter or variable?

**EDIT**: the requirement is that it must work from **coding-time**, for my static code analysis tool that im building with roslyn

Comment: coding-time, for my static code analysis tool that im building with roslyn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get it directly via properties, because in `var helloworld = sampleString;`, the statement has no context that if `sampleString` is a parameter or not. But you can get it from the method's context like this:

```
static bool IsParameter(IdentifierNameSyntax name)
{
    SyntaxNode node = name;
    while (node != null && !(node is MethodDeclarationSyntax))
    {
        node = node.Parent;
    }

    var method = node as MethodDeclarationSyntax;
    if (method != null)
    {
        return method
            .ParameterList
            .Parameters
            .Any(p => p.Identifier.Text.Equals(name.Identifier.Text));
    }

    return false;            
}
```

Using `.Parent` to get the method context of the variable, and check if any parameter in `.ParameterList` matches the identifier.

**UPDATE** Code to prove it's working:

```
SyntaxTree tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(
    @"using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    namespace HelloWorld
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string i)
            {
                var j = ""1"";
                var k = i + j;
            }
        }
    }");

var root = (CompilationUnitSyntax)tree.GetRoot();
var ns = root.Members[0] as NamespaceDeclarationSyntax;
var cls = ns.Members[0] as ClassDeclarationSyntax;
var method = cls.Members[0] as MethodDeclarationSyntax;
var statement = method.Body.Statements[1] as LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax;
var variable = statement.Declaration.Variables[0];
var binary = variable.Initializer.Value as BinaryExpressionSyntax;
var vari = binary.Left as IdentifierNameSyntax;
var varj = binary.Right as IdentifierNameSyntax;
Console.WriteLine(IsParameter(vari));   //True
Console.WriteLine(IsParameter(varj));  //False
```

**EDIT** Base on [@JeroenVannevel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1864167/jeroen-vannevel)'s comment, we can use `SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo`.

```
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("test", new[] { tree });                
var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree, true);
var symboli = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(vari);
var symbolj = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(varj);
//check symboli.Symbol.OriginalDefinition.Kind == SymbolKind.Parameter
```

Comment: yea but this is kind of done through string compare, i am more interested if theres an api or a better way to do this other than comparing by identifier name. thanks though.

Comment: @KimKangIn How can human tell if an identifier is a parameter or not? By comparing it with the parameter list, which means comparing the identifier name is the correct (and probably the only) way.

Comment: If you don't want to compare by identifier (which I agree you shouldn't) you can just get the parameter's symbol and compare it with the symbol of the local variable. Use `GetDeclaredSymbol` and `GetSymbolInfo` respectively.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel You are correct. I'll add your comment into the answer.

Comment: cool. so if i want to check if a symbol is either of 3 types: class field, local declared variable, method's parameter. i can do this: `if (symbol.Symbol.OriginalDefinition.Kind == SymbolKind.Field || symbol.Symbol.OriginalDefinition.Kind == SymbolKind.Local || symbol.Symbol.OriginalDefinition.Kind == SymbolKind.Parameter) return true `

Comment: @JeroenVannevel how does GetDeclaredSymbol works? using GetSymbolInfo is able to solve what i want but im kind of interested and want to learn more about the other apis. thanks for the help! :D

Comment: @KimKangIn `GetDeclaredSymbol` gets the symbol of a declaration while `GetSymbolInfo` gets the symbol of any other usage basically. In `int x = 5;`, `x` is a declaration (technically the entire expression is) but in `DoSomething(x)`, `x` is just a normal usage and therefore should use `GetSymbolInfo`. You can notice this most easily by looking at the syntax node type: if it has "Declaration" in the name, use `GetDeclaredSymbol`. For example: `ClassDeclarationSyntax`, `ParameterDeclarationSyntax`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Its wrong to compare identifiers by syntax or by text, imagine if the `IdentifierNameSyntax` is the name of `MemberAccessExpressionSyntax` and has the same `identifier` as a `parameter`, then you would incorrectly conclude that it is a `parameter` even though it is a `member`. You should work with the `SemanticModel` to determine what a `SymbolKind` is. You can use `SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol` on declarations and `SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo().Symbol` on symbol usages. Once you have the `ISymbol` it's easy to determine its kind. Bear in mind that different symbols have their own "sub-kinds", for instance `ITypeSymbol` has [TypeKind](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/ITypeSymbol.cs,defa3c38489da969,references) property that determines if the type is `Class`, `Struct`, `Interface`, `Array` etc., so you should check them up.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code to get the field information for class and parameters. Note, however, the detection of the method field is unavailable. This code uses reflection to query the assembly information and enumerates and compares the results.

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        SomeMethod("Hello, World!!!");

        Type testType = typeof(Program);
        FieldInfo[] fieldInfo = testType.GetFields();
        MethodInfo methodInfo = testType.GetMethod("SomeMethod");

        Console.WriteLine("Parameter type:{0}", TypeOfField(fieldInfo, methodInfo, "sampleString"));
        Console.WriteLine("Parameter type:{0}", TypeOfField(fieldInfo, methodInfo, "classField"));
        Console.WriteLine("Parameter type:{0}", TypeOfField(fieldInfo, methodInfo, "helloWorld"));
        Console.WriteLine("Parameter type:{0}", TypeOfField(fieldInfo, methodInfo, "nonexistentVariable"));

    }

    public static string classField = "Hello, World!!!";

    public static void SomeMethod(string sampleString)
    {
        string helloWorld = sampleString;
    }

    public static string TypeOfField(FieldInfo[] fieldInfo, MethodInfo methodInfo, string fieldName)
    {
        if (IsClassField(fieldInfo, fieldName))
        {
            return "Class Field";
        }
        else if (IsParameter(methodInfo, fieldName))
        {
            return "Parameter";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Cannot determine";
        }
    }

    private static bool IsClassField(FieldInfo[] fieldInfo, string classFieldName)
    {
        bool isClassField = false;

        foreach (var item in fieldInfo)
        {
            if (item.Name == classFieldName)
            {
                isClassField = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return isClassField;
    }

    private static bool IsParameter(MethodInfo methodInfo, string parameterName)
    {
        bool isParameter = false;
        ParameterInfo[] paramInfo = methodInfo.GetParameters();
        foreach (var item in paramInfo)
        {
            if (item.Name == parameterName)
            {
                isParameter = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return isParameter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Reflection is entirely separate from Roslyn. This does not answer the question.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel That was not part of the original question.

Comment: It was always tagged Roslyn and the method mentioned in the OP is also part of Roslyn.

Answer (score -2):

You can distinguish whether you are dealing with a class field vs a method's parameter or a local variable with the keyword this. If you had a class field string called sampleString and you wanted to refer to the class field rather then the local variable/ method parameter then you would refer to it with this.sampleString. You would refer to the local variable/ method parameter as sampleString without the keyword (this). In terms of local variables and method parameters, you are not able to have a local variable and method parameter with the same name within the same method. With your code above you are referring to the sampleString parameter.

Comment: That's not what OP is asking for

Comment: I mean indirectly it is, but I guess I didn't explain it clearly enough. If you use FindSymbolAtPosition on sampleString within the method, he will be using it on the parameter not the class field. If he used FindSymbolAtPosition on this.sampleString he will be using it on the class field. This is assuming that there is a local variable and a class field named sampleString. Parameters are treated vary similar to local variables, which is why you can't declare a parameter and a local variable within the same method with the same name.

Comment: In his current code snippet he is without a doubt referring to the parameter. When you have a parameter/local variable within a method that share the same name as a class field and you call it without using the keyword (this) you will always be calling the parameter/local variable, not the class field.

Comment: yea i get where you are heading. but what i want to know is if it is possible to determine, from the sampleString symbol, whether the symbol belongs to a local declaration variable, or a function parameter, or a class field.